# Is there any way to use single port to connect to multiple servers?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I mean some server-like behaviour(holding tons of clients on a single port). So im trying to connect to N servers from single local port.
Is there any way to do it?

i tried:

- multiple bind()s. - error
- dup()licating. - error

Thx in advance.

Comment: For what reason? What does `dup()` have to do with it. How does one client connecting to multiple servers constitute 'server-like behaviour'? Or 'holding tons of clients on a single port'?

Comment: I believe the OP means "server like behaviour" in the way that a server can handle multiple clients on a single port. They want it the other way around: a client connecting to multiple servers on a single port.

Comment: @DanielPorteous you are absolutely correct. This is the only similar thing i meant.

Comment: That's one rather meaningless answer to four questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because the socket object only takes only one argument.You just have to create another socket object

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use single port to connect to multiple servers?

This depends on the operating system. For example Linux 3.9 or higher has the `SO_REUSEPORT` socket option (which originated from BSD). On such a system, the following program can run successfully:

```
from socket import *
single_local_port = 12345
server1 = ('127.0.0.1', 80)     # just an example address
server2 = ('10.28.130.10', 80)  # just another example address
s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s1.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
s1.bind(('', single_local_port))
s1.connect(server1)
s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s2.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
s2.bind(('', single_local_port))# no problem binding to same port
s2.connect(server2)
```